# Swagger Status Code 200 with no Content

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger

When I call my example API in swagger i get Status 200 and no content.
I called the API using my local Swagger Ui/Editor and browser(Chrome).

I am using swagger+express and use swagger -g and the 
swagger-express-middleware

I edited my befundGet function to response with a JSON string and a console log which seems to not even run.

Why does it even run a 200 OK when my api call doesn't even call the function defined in swagger?

this is my Index.js for my node server:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var swaggerMW = require('swagger-express-middleware');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if(err){
        console.log("Connection couldn't be established");
        return false;
    }

    console.log("Connected successfully to server");
    //do stuff
    /*insertDocuments(db,function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });*/
    db.close();
});

swaggerMW('api/swagger/swagger.yaml', app, function(err, swaggerMW) {
    // Add all the Swagger Express Middleware, or just the ones you need.
    // NOTE: Some of these accept optional options (omitted here for brevity)
    app.use(
        swaggerMW.metadata(),
        swaggerMW.CORS(),
        swaggerMW.files(),
        swaggerMW.parseRequest(),
        swaggerMW.validateRequest(),
        swaggerMW.mock()
    );
});
/*
var insertDocuments = function(db, callback) {
    // Get the documents collection
    var collection = db.collection('documents');
    // Insert some documents
    collection.insertMany([
        {a : 1}, {a : 2}, {a : 3}
    ], function(err, result) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        assert.equal(3, result.result.n);
        assert.equal(3, result.ops.length);
        console.log("Inserted 3 documents into the collection");
        callback(result);
    });
}*/

function validateUser(req){
   return true
}

app.get("/",function (req,res) {
    validateUser(req);
    console.log('got req');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});
app.get("/swag",function (req,res) {
    validateUser(req);
    console.log('got req');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/swagger-ui/dist/index.html");
});
app.get("/api/swagger",function (req,res) {
    validateUser(req);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/api/swagger/swagger.yaml");
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/swagger-ui/dist'));

app.listen(4000);
```

I pretty much used the standart swaggerMW settings from the [readme](https://github.com/BigstickCarpet/swagger-express-middleware) except I removed the app.listen() from the middleware.

this is my swagger.yaml which i built using the swagger editor:

> ```
> swagger: "2.0"
> info:
>   version: "0.0.1"
>   title: Toothyfy API
>   description: The Toothyfy API for writing/getting docs from the MongoDB. Toothyfy has no production enviroment and is only available in a unstable development enviroment with constant changes.
> # during dev, should point to your local machine
> host: localhost:4000
> # basePath prefixes all resource paths
> basePath: /api
> #tags
> tags:
> - name: patients
>   description: patients API calls
> - name: befunde
>   description: befunde API calls
> - name: user
>   description: user API calls
> - name: pflegeheime
>   description: pflegeheime API calls
> #
> schemes:
>   # tip: remove http to make production-grade
>   - http
>   - https
> # format of bodies a client can send (Content-Type)
> consumes:
>   - application/json
> # format of the responses to the client (Accepts)
> produces:
>   - application/json
> paths:
>   /patients:
>     # binds swagger app logic to a route
>     x-swagger-router-controller: patients
>     get:
>       tags:
>       - patients
>       description: Returns Patients to caller
>       # used as the method name of the controller
>       operationId: patientsGet
>       parameters:
>         - name: pflegeheim
>           in: query
>           description: limit the patients to a certain pflegeheim
>           required: false
>           type: string
>       responses:
>         "200":
>           description: Success
>           schema:
>             type: array
>             items: {}
>     put:
>       tags:
>       - patients
>       description: Puts patients to DB 
>       # used as the method name of the controller
>       operationId: patientsSet
>       responses:
>         "200":
>           description: Success
>           schema:
>             type: string
>             # a pointer to a definition              
>   /pflegeheime:
>     # binds swagger app logic to a route
>     x-swagger-router-controller: pflegeheim
>     get:
>       tags:
>       - pflegeheime
>       description: Returns Pflegeheime to caller
>       # used as the method name of the controller
>       operationId: pflegeheimGet
>       parameters:
>         - name: pflegeheim
>           in: query
>           description: limit to a certain pflegeheim
>           required: false
>           type: string
>       responses:
>         "200":
>           description: Success
>           schema:
>             type: array
>             items: {}
>     put:
>       tags:
>       - pflegeheime
>       description: Puts patients to DB 
>       # used as the method name of the controller
>       operationId: pflegeheimSet
>       responses:
>         "200":
>           description: Success
>           schema:
>             type: string
>             # a pointer to a definition            
>   /user:
>     # binds swagger app logic to a route
>     x-swagger-router-controller: user
>     get:
>       tags:
>       - user
>       description: Returns all the user docs to caller
>       # used as the method name of the controller
>       operationId: userGet
>       parameters:
>         - name: token
>           in: query
>           description: token to identify the user
>           required: true
>           type: string
>       responses:
>         "200":
>           description: Success
>           schema:
>             type: array
>             items: {}
>     put:
>       tags:
>       - user
>       description: Puts user specific docs to DB 
>       # used as the method name of the controller
>       operationId: userSet
>       parameters:
>         - name: token
>           in: query
>           description: token to identify the user
>           required: true
>           type: string
>       responses:
>         "200":
>           description: Success
>           schema:
>             type: string
>             # a pointer to a definition          
>   /befunde:
>     x-swagger-router-controller: befunde
>     get:
>       tags:
>       - befunde
>       description: gets befunde to caller
>       # used as the method name of the controller
>       operationId: befundeGet
>       parameters:
>         - name: token
>           in: query
>           description: token to identify the user
>           required: true
>           type: string
>         - name: patientID
>           in: query
>           description: PatientId from the patient which befunde you try to retrieve 
>           required: true
>           type: string
>       responses:
>         "200":
>           description: OK     
>     put:
>       tags:
>       - befunde
>       description: Puts user specific docs to DB 
>       # used as the method name of the controller
>       operationId: befundeSet
>       parameters:
>         - name: token
>           in: query
>           description: token to identify the user
>           required: true
>           type: string
>       responses:
>         "200":
>           description: Success
>           schema:
>             type: string
>             # a pointer to a definition
> ```

this is the befund.js which is in /api/controllers:

```
module.exports = {
    befundeGet: befundeGet,
    befundeSet: befundeSet
};


function befundeGet(req,res){
        var name = 'stranger';
        console.log(req);
        console.log('Befunde get');
        var hello = util.format('Hello, %s', name);
        res.json(hello);
}

function befundeSet(req,res){

}
```

It seems to not even run my befundeGet function because my node console stays empty after an API call.